# Generate point within bounds of rectangle that is a minimum distance but not more than max distance from a given point A

Tags: performance, random, coordinates, distribution

I am working on a hobby project and have run into an issue that I wonder if there is a "simple" solution for.

**The problem is as follows:**

Assume a 2-dimensional grid with a rectangle defined by 4 points, (x0,y0) (x0,y1) (x1,y0) (x1,y1).

Assume a point A always within the bounds of the rectangle.

Generate a point B that has a Euclidean distance of at least d_min and at most d_max, that is within the bounds of x1, y1, x2, y2.

**What I have tried:**

So far my naive approach has been to generate a point with the correct Euclidean distance and then check if it's within the bounds. If it is not, I generate another and check, repeating until I find a result. The issue with this is that it's of course not particularly performant. I am wondering if there is a more performant solution or if there is a known algorithim that solves this issue. To help visualize the question I made a quick sketch. The gray area would be the valid area to generate point B in. [image: Example]

**EDIT:**

d_max and d_min are constants. The value of A is variable and can be anywhere within the rectangle bounds. d_max can not be said to always be less than min(x_1-A_x, y_1-A_y). In other words, the ring follows A around with the inner circle of the ring at a constant radius from A equal to d_min and the outer circle of the ring at a constant radius from A equal to d_max.

A single point B is sufficient, however it should be random within the gray area. A perfect distribution in generated locations is not necessarily required, a good approximation is sufficient.

If A is placed in the middle of the rectangle, it is guaranteed that any point within the d_min/d_max will be always within the bounds of the rectangle. I.e:

- d_max < 0.5(x_1-x_0)
- d_max < 0.5(y_1-y_0)

Comment: Do you just want one single B for a given A, or lots of them? Is the location of B required to be random in the grey area?

Comment: Is `d_max<min(x_1-A_x,y_1-A_y)` always?

Comment: @Argyll d_max and d_min are constants. The value of A is variable and can be anywhere within the rectangle bounds. d_max can not be said to always be less than min(x_1-A_x, y_1-A_y). In other words, the ring follows A around with the inner circle of the ring at a constant radius from A equal to d_min and the outer circle of the ring at a constant radius from A equal to d_max.

Comment: @MarkSetchell a single B is sufficient but the location should be random in the gray area.

Comment: There is a non-analytical, approach. You could draw the rectangle in blue using PIL/OpenCV (or any drawing package) and then draw the disk in red. And then randomly pick a magenta (purple) pixel. Or, faster and less RAM, do the analogous thing in greyscale.

Comment: @erikp: "any point within the d_min/d_max will be always within the bounds of the rectangle" <-- if this is true, I expect that you can use my solution directly. (Direct means having a *non-segmented* analytical expression for CDF inverse on radius.) I suggest you give it a read. Separately, I don't think your listed conditions (the "ie." parts) guarantees the statement. For example, make A a quarter way to (x_1,y_1) and make `d_max=0.4*min(x_1,y_1)`. That way, your listed conditions are fulfilled but the statement is not.

Answer (score 1):

###### Assuming `d_max<min(x_1-A_x,y_1-A_y)`

*You might be able to generalize the same approach by segmenting the valid regions if that is not the case.*

Step 1: Generate (randomized) distance to A. Call it radius. This radius should have weights proportional to the circular segments within bound. That means you first generate a point in [0,1] with a uniformly distributed generator and map the generated point through the inverse of the CDF of radius. More on its CDF later.

Step 2: Conditionally generate angle relative to (0,1) vector with the range determined by the coordinates of A and the earlier radius.

Step 3: Convert radius and angle to Cartesian coordinates

---

The natural way for you to generate a point as described in your diagram is for the generated points to uniformly distribute over the valid region. In other words, the probability of finding a point in any sub-region should be proportional to its area.

To fulfill the above, we need to work out the cumulated distribution of radius based on `A_x` (x-coordinate of A), `A_y`, `d_min` and `d_max`, which is:

- F(r) = (area of disk from d_min to r) / (area of disk from d_min to d_max)

You need the respective areas within bounds. And you can work out the analytical expression of F(r) and then its inverse ahead of programming. (Maybe use a symbolic computational tool such as Mathematica to validate your answer. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) is a related tool.)

With `F(r)` inverse, you generate a point randomly distributed on `[0,1]`. That will be the value of `F(r)` and you solve for `r` using the inverse we had from earlier.

And that `r` will be the radius.

You then find the intersects between `r^2=(x_x-A_x)^2+(x_y-A_y)^2` your boundary lines respectively, which are `y=0` and `x=0`. Those intersects would form the range for angle, which you then use a uniformly distributed random number for.

With radius and angle, you can convert to Cartesian coordinates.

This is as performant as it gets because you are not generating invalid points and discarding them with a high probability of generating invalid points. You need two random numbers per point which cannot be reduced further unless you discretize the real numbers (as represented by doubles, for example). So the only thing potentially above minimal computation is the requirements to calculate F(r) inverse and to find intersects. You do have analytical expressions for those. They probably contain `sqrt`. Still, that should be much faster compared to discarding points at quantity.

Comment: It should be noted that (assuming you want the probability of a point being in a region proportional to the region's area), picking a random radius needs to be proportional to the radius (e.g. picking R=10 should be twice as likely as R=5). It's also possible to have up to 8 intersections with the bounding box, resulting in up to 4 disjoint regions to pick the angle from.

Comment: @user137794: I edited my answer accordingly. Thank you for the prompt. Feel free to take a look and provide further critiques. As for the bounds, I am going to leave the answer with assuming `d_max<min(x_1-A_x,y_1-A_y)`, ie. the diagram in OP being fully representative.

Comment: There is still the possibility of 2 disjoint regions for the angle. I'm under the impression that the steps detailed here are as good as it gets, and a proper implementation would have to deal with the disjoint regions no matter what (making the `d_max` assumption unnecessary).

Comment: I've also realized that this doesn't actually result in the desired distribution, since the CDF depends on how the the region clips with the bounds :c. But when `d_min` and `d_max` are close together, it's a very good approximation.

Comment: @user137794: The area division itself shouldn't be wrong. But how the disk clips the rectangular region would determine whether there is a singular analytical expression for the CDF (without having to use conditional ranges). If you require the outer circle to be fully contained within the rectangle, the disk should clip the rectangle the way the diagram presents, right?